# Django 'attempt to write a readonly database' even if db file has read and write permissions

Tags: django, ubuntu, file-permissions

I am using SQLite3, Ubuntu server. I have checked the read and write permissions of the database file. It is:
`-rw-r--r--`
Doesn't this mean that the file has read and write access? So why is Django error saying `attempt to write a readonly database`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Who owns the file? Who runs as Django? Temporarily make it world writable (`sudo chmod 666 db.sqlite`) to see if that helps. If it does, the file is owned by someone else than Django.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Selcuk! This helped me a lot!

Comment: No worries, but don't leave it that way as it is insecure. Find out the correct user and change the owner using `sudo chown <username> db.sqlite` then revert to the old attributes (`sudo chmod 644 db.sqlite`).

Answer (score 0):

I configured with el user and group that inside of httpd.conf  (/opt/lampp/etc/)
of following code :

user@server:/opt/lampp$ sudo chown --recursive daemon:daemon htdocs/website/
user@server:/opt/lampp$ sudo ./lampp restart

//PD : the name user daemon is in the archive httpd.conf